# Query Excel Sheet to get subset of data in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am currently working on processing Excel sheets using Apache POI. Now I am in a tricky situation where in I want a subset of data based on certain conditions.

In the sense that I have to get only the data which satisfies certain conditions, essentially a select query.

```
select distinct(category) from #Sheet where id < 10
```

I understand the above thing is possible in C#, but how do I achieve the same in Java using Apache POI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I worked with POI (about 1 year ago) there were no querying APIs.

However, if your query is really that simple, you should just scan the rows in Java and add the categories to a `Set<String>` (or `Map<String,Integer>` if you want to count them as well).

Comment: Excellent , this kind of worked out.
Looks like POI should include this as part of the package :)